# Problems while installing Play Framework 1.2.7

Tags: java, linux, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have been trying to install Play Framework on Linux, Ubuntu 16.04. I have downloaded Play Framework from here https://downloads.typesafe.com/play/1.2.7.2/play-1.2.7.2.zip
created a directory named play-framework and unpacked the archive there. Then I tried to export environment variable like this
 export PATH=$PATH:/home/codeinside/play-framework/play
but play command still not working from console
help please

Answer (score 1):

You can have the instance of Play sitting within reach of your application code. You could then reference the Play executable

```
./play [play-command] path/to/app-code
```

Alternatively, if you'd like one instance of the framework for all your projects, you can define an alias in your .bashrc file like

```
alias play='/path/to/play-framework/play'
```

or in your case:

```
alias play='/home/codeinside/play-framework/play'
```

If you choose this route, remember to run `source /path/to/.bashrc` for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to use a very very old version of Play? Any reason for it? Go to the [Play's download page](https://www.playframework.com/download), and gets the latest version; and then you should be able to use `sbt` or `gradle` to build and run your project easily.